# Laravel 4, group prefix requires changing route names. Really?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I've been working on an app that lived on the domain root and now has to work on /admin. So URLs like `domain.com/[resource]` should now be `domain.com/admin/[resource]`. I didn't thought this very well before since I assumed that this had to be a very easy fix on Laravel. After all, that's one of the main reasons for not hardcoding routes, right?

So my routes.php file looked something like:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('books', 'BooksController');
    ... more resources here ...
});
```

Going through the docs I found that `'prefix' => 'admin'` would do the trick:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('books', 'BooksController');
    ... more resources here ...
});
```

But it turns out that every route name get's changed from `books.{action}` to `admin.books.{action}` which requires me to change the whole app. Regexing would be dangerous and doing it manually would be annoying. Laravel was supposed to help with this! Or am I missing something?

Comment: This isn't unreasonable behavior. It prevents an admin "users" resource from conflicting with a public "users" resource by namespacing the routes. I agree there should be a little more control over it but the opposite behavior would be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but after looking on the documentation for [resource controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) it seems as though you can manually set their names.  I'm assuming Laravel automatically namespaces grouped resource controller routes to avoid name collision, but you can override this to avoid going back through the rest of your app (just beware of future name collision):

```
Route::resource(
    'books',
    'BooksController',
    array(
        'names' => array(
            'index'   => 'photo.index',
            'create'  => 'photo.create',
            'store'   => 'photo.store',
            'show'    => 'photo.show',
            'edit'    => 'photo.edit',
            'update'  => 'photo.update',
            'destroy' => 'photo.destroy',
        )
    )
);
```

---

**Shorter Method:**

Just define a quick method at the top of your `routes.php` file to shorten up this repetitive task of creating an array of route names.  Still not the greatest solution, but I believe its the only thing you can do with how Laravel has this set up.

```
function createRouteNames($resource) {
    $names = array();
    $types = ['index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'];
    foreach($types as $type) {
        $names[$type] = $resource . '.' . $type;
    }
    return $names;
}

Route::resource('books', 'BooksController', ['names' => createRouteNames('books')]);
```

*Note:* `[] === array()` and may not be supported on older PHP's, meaning you may need to replace them with the old syntax.

Comment: It does work. However, it's a pretty ugly solution. It makes my routes.php file about 10 times larger!

Comment: @Mauro check out my update with a function to create this name array for your resource controllers.

Comment: Haha, I did think on that. But I prefer the long routes.php file. It's not always about the length of the file but also about complexity. I'm trying to make the file easy to read to others and including a function would be over complicating it. Thanks a lot for the approach though. I'll wait a bit longer before marking your answer as correct.

Comment: No problem, I agree with your points. Maybe its worth splitting them into a directory with multiple route files (for each group) that will all be included by the main `routes.php`?

Comment: Bah, I'll just leave it like that. I just wished Laravel to have a neater way of doing it. Like naming the routes for the whole resource with a wildcard like `books.{action}` or sth.